# My Deep Neural network for L no.of layers is not working properly

Tags: python, deep-learning, neural-network, backpropagation

[Github link for entire code](https://github.com/SriramR474/Deep-Neural-Network)

I have coded the Forward and Back Propagation algorithm for a Deep neural network from scratch. I am using Gradient descent to reduce cost error, however, the cost does not seem to decrease when I am using 3 hidden layers. any recommendations to improve my code? is there any bug in it?

I have mentioned my entire Github code link here.

def backward_propagation(parameters, AL, cache, X, Y):

```
m = X.shape[1]

L = len(parameters)//2
grads = {}   
cache['A' + str(0)] = X


dZ = AL-Y
A_prev = cache['A' + str(L-1)]
dW = (1/m)*np.dot(dZ,A_prev.T)
db = (1/m)*np.sum(dZ,axis=1,keepdims=True)

grads["dW"+str(L)] = dW
grads["db"+str(L)] = db
grads["dZ"+str(L)] = dZ

   
for l in range(L-1,0,-1): # from reverse
    
    A = cache['A' + str(l)]      
    W = parameters['W' + str(l+1)]
    dZ_next = grads["dZ"+str(l+1)]
    A_prev = cache['A' + str(l-1)]
    
    temp = np.zeros(A.shape)
    temp[A < 0] = 0
    temp[A >= 0] = 1
    
    
    dZ = np.dot(W.T,dZ_next)*temp
    dW = (1/m)*np.dot(dZ,A_prev.T)
    db = (1/m)*np.sum(dZ,axis=1,keepdims=True)
    
    grads["dW"+str(l)] = dW
    grads["db"+str(l)] = db
    grads["dZ"+str(l)] = dZ


return grads
```

Comment: what is your data size? with neural networks you need good sized data? how many epochs?

Comment: My data size is 209. Actually, I have used the same amount of data in Logistic regression and for a 1-layer Neural network. Both of them gave high training accuracy than the 3 layered Neural networks.

Comment: neural network requires way more data than SVG or Logistic Regression. if you have small data set then consider using pre trained model

Comment: whats the benchmark score vs the deep architecture score? it is not always a case that a deeper network will work better, have you performed grid search for the shape of the layers?

Comment: actually, in my Coursera course, they have used the same no.of samples to train a 3-layered NN. Their cost function kept on reducing. They didn't use any pre-trained model. but while I tried to implement it, my cost function didn't reduce.

Comment: is my backpropagation implementation correct? are there any bugs in it?

Comment: @RitwickJha Logistic regression training accuracy was 92%, and 1 hidden layer NN accuracy was 98%. But for the 3 hidden layers, the NN accuracy I am getting is 65%.

Comment: what do you mean by training accuracy? is the loss converging for deep? have you tried a grid search for shape of the layers and learning rate and other hyper params because they will determine how fast the convergence happens or if it even coverges?

Comment: @RitwickJha. training accuracy means the accuracy I got for the data on which I have trained the model. and for the test dataset, I got 34% accuracy. Loss is not converging. it becomes saturated after some iterations. yes, I figured out the shapes of the layers. I have printed those shapes in my Github coding as well. can you please take a look at my code? The Github link is given in the question itself.